# how to define const function javascript (syntactic sugar)?

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6, constants, syntactic-sugar

I expect to be able to create a function like:

```
const function doSomething(){...}
```

Yet looks like the only way to achieve it is:

```
const doSomething=function(){...}
```

Am I wrong? or is there actually a syntactic sugar for it?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do in the first one?  or the 2nd one too.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: JS' `const` is not the same as C++ `const`. It doesn't indicate what the function does at all.

Comment: Not trying to make a function return a constant value, just trying to avoid it can be reassigned and consequently changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) does in JavaScript is prevent re-assignment of a variable. Not to be confused with preventing mutation of a value.

`const` requires an identifier, an assignment operator, and a right-hand side. The only way to combine `const` with a function is with a function expression (your second example).

```
const doSomething = function() {
  // do stuff
};
// will either throw an error or the value of doSomething simply won't change
doSomething = somethingElse;
```

Many people like to make sure their functions are named so that the name appears in the call stack and as such prefer to use function declarations (your first example). However, it's possible to name a function expression.

```
const doSomething = function doSomething() {
  // name will appear as doSomething in the call stack
};
```

Comment: Note, in a real ES6 environment, or with Babel, the function name is added automatically, so you can assign an anonymous function without worrying about the debugability of the call stack.